# Python enum set as parameter in a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, enums, set

I am looking at an python API with the following function example:

```
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED', pass_filter={"DIFFUSE", "DIRECT"})
```

while the `pass_filter` parameter accepts one or more of any of the following:

```
pass_filter (enum set in {
        'NONE', 'AO', 'EMIT',
        'DIRECT', 'INDIRECT',
        'COLOR', 'DIFFUSE', 'GLOSSY',
        'TRANSMISSION', 'SUBSURFACE',
        })
```

on the other hand I have the following to determine whether or not the parameters should be added to `pass_filter`:

```
is_NONE = False
is_AO = True
is_EMIT = False
is_DIRECT = True
#..etc.
```

How do I insert these to the function, like a list or array to the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is knowing `{"DIFFUSE", "DIRECT"}` represents a set:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
is_NONE = False
is_AO = True
is_EMIT = False
is_DIRECT = True
pass_filter = set()
if is_AO:
    pass_filter.add('AO')  
if is_DIRECT:
    pass_filter.add('DIRECT')  
print(pass_filter)
```

See it [here](https://code.sololearn.com/chI1DMJqwtzD/#py)

Feel free to add your extra if statements!